# Cannot add .NET 5 source code as a project reference

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I've downloaded .NET 5 according to [these](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/docs/BuildFromSource.md) instructions.
I can build the Antiforgery.slnf in Visual Studio with no errors.
I've added it as a project reference in a different solution with an ASP.NET Core 5 app.
But I'm getting these errors:

> '..\..\..\..\..\..\aspnetcore\src\Antiforgery\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.csproj' targets 'net6.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0'.   AntiForgeryTest C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  1662
>
> NU1201    Project Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Project Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) AntiForgeryTest C:\Users\Davidk\source\repos\AntiForgeryTest\WebApplication2\AntiforgeryTest.csproj 1

[image]

It seems as though the current version of ASP.NET Core source code in Github is version net6.0, and the current version available in Visual Studio when creating a new project is only net5.0.

Do I need to get version net5.0 of the source code? I'd prefer to not have to do that since it's taken me hours just to get the .NET Core source code to build.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.8.2 and here is the list of the installed SDKs:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? The `master` branch contains the source code currently in development which *is* .NET 6. .NET 5 has already been released. You need to clone using the proper tag.

Comment: Or maybe just `git checkout release/5.0`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to add the source code to my project so I can debug it.

Comment: I think it SourceLink enabled, so you can just enable SourceLink support and disable Just My Code option in debug settings to step-in into source code

Comment: SourceLink is the better option since then you won't have to download all the source and it will use the source for the version of .Net that your project is targeting.